# Dependency injection: HttpClient or HttpClientFactory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient

Everywhere I can see three main approaches to create clients (basic, named, typed) in DI, but I have found nowhere if to inject `IHttpClientFactory` or `HttpClient` (both possible).

**Q1**: What is the difference between injecting `IHttpClientFactory` or `HttpClient` please?

**Q2**: And if `IHttpClientFactory` is injected, should I use `factory.CreateClient()` for each call?

Comment: When I set in startup.cs `services.AddHttpClient(c => { c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/"); });` and inject `HttpClient` into my service, it should use the same client as if I inject `IHttpClientFactory.CreateClient()`, right?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

#### Summary

- `HttpClient` can only be injected inside **Typed** clients
- for other usages, you need `IHttpClientFactory`
- In both scenarios, the lifetime of `HttpClientMessageHandler` is managed by the framework, so you are not worried about (incorrectly) disposing the `HttpClients`.

#### Examples

In order to directly inject `HttpClient`, you need to register a specific **Typed** service that will receive the client:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<GithubClient>(c => c.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://api.github.com"));
```

Now we can inject that inside the **typed** GithubClient

```cs
public class GithubClient
{
    public GithubClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        // client.BaseAddress is "https://api.github.com"
    }
}
```

You can't inject the `HttpClient` inside `AnotherClient`, because **it is not typed** to `AnotherClient`

```cs
public class AnotherClient
{
    public AnotherClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        // InvalidOperationException, can't resolve HttpClient 
    }
}
```

You can, however:
 1. Inject the `IHttpClientFactory` and call `CreateClient()`. This client will have `BaseAddress` set to `null`.
 2. Or configure `AnotherClient` as a different typed client with, for example, a different `BaseAdress`.

#### Update

Based on your comment, you are registering a **Named** client. It is still resolved from the IHttpClientFactory.CreateClient() method, but you need to pass the 'name' of the client

**Registration**

```cs
services.AddHttpClient("githubClient", c => c.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://api.github.com"));
```

**Usage**

```cs
// note that we inject IHttpClientFactory
public HomeController(IHttpClientFactory factory)
{
    this.defaultClient = factory.CreateClient(); // BaseAddress: null
    this.namedClient = factory.CreateClient("githubClient"); // BaseAddress: "https://api.github.com"
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry, the first param of AddHttpClient I have is `string.Empty`

Comment: updated the answer based on your comment and clarified the examples (I _hope_ :D)

Comment: What if I what to use `HttpClient` in an `ActionFilterAttribute`? In that case, you need to use `context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService` to get the services instead of the constructor.

Comment: in `.net 6` when adding `AddHttpClient()` if i inject the IHttpClientFactory type the app throws exception like is not present in app container, but if i inject the `HttpClient` type directly works correctly.

Comment: @MatteoPietroPeru is this in the context of an ASP.NET Core 6.0 project?

Answer (score 11):

Sadly I cannot comment, but only Post an answer. Therefore I suggest you should check out the following Links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Regarding your Questions it more or Less boils down to this:

**Q1** -> IHttpClientFactory handles the connection pools of HttpClient instances and this will help you regarding load and dispose problems as discribed in the links, if the HttpClient is used wrong.

**Q2** -> yes you should use factory.create client according to microsoft docs

Comment: So if I inject `HttpClient` instead of `IHttpClientFactory` (although I have the same startup.cs setup), I loose the factory features (pooling, etc.), right? I thought it does not matter.

Comment: Some Additional Points

As the HttpClientFactory internally Create HttpMessageHandler Objects. So each time you create a new HttpClientFactory Object , internally, you are creating up the HttpMessageHandler Object. and there is a chain of HttpMessageHandler.

Benefits of HttpClientFactory

It reuses the existing HttpMessageHandler instances if the one is available to use , if it is not , it will create a new HttpMessageHandler Instance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use factory.CreateClient() for each call. I mean you should "not" write this code in the constructor of a singleton or scoped service. But a usage like below where you are not doing it for each call is fine: See here, we are not creating httpClient for every call. Even if you create a httpClient per call, there won't be much impact in perf, since the underlying HttpClientHandler for the created httpClients are pooled and shared. So only overhead is a small c# object getting created everytime.

```cs
public class BasicModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public BasicModel(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) =>
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;

    public IEnumerable<GitHubBranch>? GitHubBranches { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<StackOverFlowAnswer>? StackOverFlowAnswers { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        var httpRequestMessage1 = new HttpRequestMessage(
            HttpMethod.Get,
            "https://api.github.com/repos/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/branches")
        {
            Headers =
            {
                { HeaderNames.Accept, "application/vnd.github.v3+json" },
                { HeaderNames.UserAgent, "HttpRequestsSample" }
            }
        };

        var httpRequestMessage2 = new HttpRequestMessage(
            HttpMethod.Get,
            "https://api.stackoverflow.com/something")
        {
            Headers =
            {
                { HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json" },
                { HeaderNames.UserAgent, "HttpRequestsSample" }
            }
        };

        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var httpResponseMessage1 = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage1);

        if (httpResponseMessage1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            using var contentStream =
                await httpResponseMessage1.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            
            GitHubBranches = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
                <IEnumerable<GitHubBranch>>(contentStream);
        }

        var httpResponseMessage2 = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage2);

        if (httpResponseMessage2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            using var contentStream =
                await httpResponseMessage2.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            
            StackOverFlowAnswers= await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
                <IEnumerable<StackOverFlowAnswer>>(contentStream);
        }

    }
}
```

Now coming to your Q1, it depends. When you inject HttpClient to a service which is not a typed client, that HttpClient instance is actually created by the IHttpClientFactory only ( assuming you have done services.AddHttpClient(); in startup.cs) "transiently". Here "transiently" being the important word. So whenever that constructor is called, a new HttpClient instance is created and passed to that constructor. And if the calling constructor is for a singleton, then it's incorrect usage. [HttpClient inject into Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70924783/httpclient-inject-into-singleton)

Some important considerations are:

1. What is the scope (lifetime) of the class in question. If it is transient, then there is no difference in injecting either IHttpClientFactory or HttpClient. But if the scope is singleton, then injecting HttpClient into the constructor is bad usage.
2. Either way, it is IHttpClientFactory which is used to create the injected HttpClients, so its same.

Any HttpClient that you are not creating ( using new HttpClient()) should be short-lived. Even if you are creating a HttpClient and using it as a singleton, its incorrect at DNS Changes might not be honoured.