# How do I operate around Stack Exchange API in .NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, api

How can do I work with StackOverflow API and HTTP request it?

This is my problem: I want to get first 1000 tags from Stack Exchange API, see their popularity and usage.

This is what I've done so far:

1. Created an ASP.NET MVC project
2. Added HTTP Client in `Startup.cs` file:

   ```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddHttpClient("stackoverflow", s =>
        {
            s.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3");
            s.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("client_id", "1");
            s.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("site", "stackoverflow");
            s.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("redirect_uri", "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/tags?");
        });
    }
   ```
3. Created classes `Tags` and interface `ITagsRepository`:

   ```
    public class Tags
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Popularity { get; set; }
        public decimal Usage { get; set; }
    }

    public class TagsRepository : ITagsRepository
    {
        public Tags GetTag(int id)
        {
            // put logic in here
        }
    }
   ```
4. I also have added a `TagsController` in `HomeController.cs`:

   ```
    public class TagsController : Tags
    {
        private ITagsRepository _tagsRepository;

        public TagsController(ITagsRepository tagsRepository)
        {
            _tagsRepository = tagsRepository;
        }

        public IActionResult GetTag(int id)
        {
            Tags tag = _tagsRepository.GetTag(id);
            return View(tag);
        }
    }
   ```

My question is: how do I make my code run in `index.cshtml` and how do I make http requests that are customisable from client side?

Comment: I have voted to close as duplicate of [Dependency injection: HttpClient or HttpClientFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59280153/dependency-injection-httpclient-or-httpclientfactory) as the first obstacle, although not the only one, is to get the HttpClient registered in startup into your repository class. The accepted answer explains how to do that. (What you have is a "named client").

Comment: N.b. `TagsController` doesn't need to inherit from `Tags`, so remove that. I don't think it will cause a problem, it just doesn't make any sense.