# HttpClient inject into Singleton

Tags: c#, .net-core

Lets say we have code like this:

```
services.AddHttpClient();
services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();

...

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public MyService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
    }
}
```

There are questions (probably stupid, but I just want to clear some things):

1. Will it use `HttpClientFactory` to create an instance of `HttpClient`?
2. I guess it uses `HttpClientFactory` but will it have issues with DNS changes in that case?

It's not quite clear if `HttpMessageHandler`s will be managed for singleton services, and should service be scoped anyway to get all benefits of `HttpClientFactory` usage.

Comment: Have you tried to inject `IHttpClientFactory` instead of `HttpClient`?

Comment: You are right, I think it should be `IHttpClientFactory`, just was curious if such inject will also work, but yeah, should be `IHttpClientFactory` I guess

Comment: Why don't create a [typed httpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#how-to-use-typed-clients-with-ihttpclientfactory) and inject that to your `MyService`?

Comment: @PeterCsala but will typed client be created and managed differently from just `AddHttpClient` approach?

Comment: Under the hood both will use [`DefaultHttpClientFactory`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs) to create an HttpClient instance. The difference is the responsibility segregation. If you have a typed client than it deals with the Http communication only, whereas your `MyService` deals with everything else. In your proposed solution both Http communication and everything else are handled inside your singleton.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> 1. Will it use `HttpClientFactory` to create an instance of `HttpClient`?

Yes. A default `HttpClient` is registered as a transient service during [HttpClientFactory registration](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L56-L60).

> 2. I guess it uses `HttpClientFactory` but will it have issues with DNS changes in that case?

Correct, it still would. As you inject it into a singleton, `HttpClient` here will be created only once. In order to make use of `HttpClientFactory`'s `HttpMessageHandler` pooling, you'd need your `HttpClient`s to be short-lived. So, for this you would rather need to inject `IHttpClientFactory` itself and call `CreateClient` when you need one. (Note that short-living `HttpClient`s only apply to `HttpClientFactory` usage). BTW switching to a typed client will not help when injecting into a singleton, `HttpClient` will still end up being created only once, see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64034.

Also, you can actually avoid `HttpClientFactory` entirely and still have DNS changes respected. For that you may have a static/singleton `HttpClient` with `PooledConnectionLifetime` set to some reasonable timeout (e.g. the same 2 minutes `HttpClientFactory` does)

```cs
services.AddSingleton(() => new HttpClient(
    new SocketsHttpHandler { PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2) }
));
```