# Too many TCP connections in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function that during an evening load adds a certain number of items in a storage queue and the worker start the process straight away.

What I noticed is that there are an incredible amount of TCP connection opened in that period and quite often the function or another function running on the same server crashes and it complains that there is a lack of resources.

The queue is a storage queue and the number of items is in the range of 2k/20k. Each item gets processed in a range between 1 and 30 seconds and there are also other storage queues involved but they are not as big.

What I have found is that 2000 connections to the storage queue are open in a short period of time but they hang for 4 minutes before being closed.

The function signature:

```
[FunctionName("LongOperation")]
 public async Task Schedule(
     [TimerTrigger("%SCHEDULE_BEGINNING_OF_DAY_OPERATIONS%")] TimerInfo myTimer,
     [Queue(QueueImport1)] IAsyncCollector<Import1QueueItem> queueImport1,
     [Queue(QueueImport2)] IAsyncCollector<Import2QueueItem> queueImport2)
 {
...
 }
```

And then the code that adds to the queues (removed all the rest for brevity):

```
foreach (var item in itemsToProcess)
{
   await queueImport1.AddAsync(new Import1QueueItem{ItemId = item.Id, Code = item.Code }, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Is there a way to control how the connection queue is made from the funcion?

Note: This has nothing to do with HttpClient

Comment: if this is a self-answer question, just make the question clear and leave an answer on how you solved it. that would also be fine.

Comment: You are supposed to cache `HttpClient` not recreate it, even if you dispose it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpClient inject into Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70924783/httpclient-inject-into-singleton)

Comment: @RuudHelderman No, this describes how I am using the HttpClient

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify the situation, preferably with code. How are your singleton services registered in the DI container? Are you injecting HttpClient in those services, or IHttpClientFactory?

Answer (score 0):

when you say 'I have checked all HttpClient instantiations and none of them are the 'leaky' type.', it looks like you're not using HttpClientFactory and it will lead to tcp port exaustion.

https://www.serverlessnotes.com/docs/correct-way-to-use-http-client-in-azure-functions

Comment: thanks for the answer, I think the info about HttpClient was just misleading and so I removed it