# Change response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync to await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync

Tags: c#, .net

I have problem with code:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (requestMessage, certificate, chain, policyErrors) => true;
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "https://adr.adr"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "HCP user:pass");

        var response = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(request);
        var responseString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);
        return Ok(responseString);

    }
}
```

Please help, this line not works, i tried other examples but only this works (but with                                                `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`):

```
var response = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(request);
```

Comment: When you say something doesn't work, you need to explain why it doesn't work. Do you get a compile error? Runtime error? Exception messages? What is your expected input and output etc.

Comment: Compile Error cannot convert from  HttpClientHandler to String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetByteArrayAsync` doesn't have any overloads which accept an HttpRequestMessage - it expects a url as either a `string` or a `Uri`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getbytearrayasync?view=net-7.0

Try this instead:

```cs
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "HCP user:pass");
    var response = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync("https://adr.adr");
    var responseString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);
    return Ok(responseString);
}
```

You probably don't want to be creating a new `HttpClient` on each request though, I'd suggest injecting `IHttpClientFactory` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59281244/5369074